# creating identical formating after text document modification in R

Tags: r, format, document

I am trying to modify a text document with a specific header information that is separate from the data frame:

Picture of document: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4jQ7.jpg

Copy of document: http://www.filedropper.com/elist

I can load in the document and edit it fine:

```
data <- read.table('elist.txt')

d <- data[!(data$V3==1),] # removes pointless 1 triggers
d2 <- d[!(d$V3>199),] # removes probe triggers
d3 <- d2[!(d2$V3<4),] # removes probes more triggers
d4 <- d3[!(d3$V3 == shift(d3$V3)),] # removes duplicate triggers
d5 <- d4[!(d4$V3 == shift(d4$V3+1)),] # removes +1 duplicate triggers
```

However, I do not know how to export the document so it contains the same header information - simply using the write.table() function does not seem to work.

My question is, how can I modify documents while keeping the formatting identical as possible to the original?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read initial lines with `readLines`

```
heading_text <- readLines('elist.txt') # read all lines
heading_text <- heading_text[grepl("^#", unlist(l))] # subset comment lines (starting with #)
heading_text <- trimws(gsub("^#|\\\t", " ", heading_text)) # trim whites, remove initial # and the tab separator flag (\t)
```

You can pick the header line using `regex`. In this case I picked the line that had the word *item* in it. Then you need to trim multiple whites and set a column separator.

```
header <- gsub("\\s+", ",", heading_text[grepl("item", heading_text)])
header <- unlist(strsplit(header, ","))
```

You should pay attention to the fact that the data is not read correctly; there are 12 columns while your header has a length of 11. You need to fix that. In this example I've just dropped the last column

```
data <- read.table('elist.txt')
data <- data[1:11]
names(data) <- header
head(data)
```

Comment: Thank you, I"ll try to implement this code.  Note that the reason there seems to be 12 columns is because it is treating '[' and ']' as separate column entries when it should be one '[   ]'.